# MediaWiki Template for external URL

Tags: mediawiki

I've created a few templates on our WIKI and I have a basic understanding of how they work.  I have one template I'm working on right now that refuses to behave, at least not the way I expect it to.  The purpose of the template is to format a external link in a consistent way.  The name of the template is "NSURL"

Here is the template markup:

> [{{{1}}} Go...]

I'm using it like this:

> {{NSURL | https://www.somesecreturl.com}}

When I use the template it prints it out just like the raw template markup.  If I replace {{{1}}} with a static URL it works correctly:

> [http://www.yahoo.com Go...]

----- Version Info -----

> MediaWiki  1.15.1
>
> PHP    5.2.6-1+lenny3 (apache2handler)
>
> MySQL  5.0.51a-24+lenny1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Steve K - here's my code for an external link to a Wikipedia URL:

```
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{{1|Main_Page}}} {{{2|{{{1|Wikipedia}}}}}}]
```

Use:

- `{{Wikipedia|Agile}}` gives [Agile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile)
- `{{Wikipedia|Agile_software_development|Agile software development}}` gives [Agile software development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development)

**See also** notes below regarding special characters like ? etc.

**Update:** if you have [Extension:StringFunctions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aStringFunctions) you can use [#replace](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aStringFunctions#.23replace%3a) in the second example. This means that the URL will replace *spaces* with *underscores*. So the code in the template will be:

```
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{#replace:{{{1|Main_Page}}}| |_}} {{{2|{{{1|Wikipedia}}}}}}]
```

and on the page you only need:

- `{{Wikipedia|Agile software development}}`

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for sharing but if I modify your example to take a full URL as a parameter I still get the same thing as my original post.  Any chance you could try the template that I posted to see if you receive a different result?  If not I completely understand.

Comment: @SteveK - for me it works fine. Here's what I did - can you repeat? 1. create a template called urltest (so the page is **Template:urltest**). 2. Put this on the template: **[{{{1}}} urltest]** 3. On another page, put this: **{{Urltest|http://www.google.com/}}** 4. Tell me what happens. Good luck! Note: step 3 should show **h t t p : / / w w w .** first but this editor does not show that.

Comment: @Mark - I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was including a space between the vertical pipe and my URL.  I'm used to doing this with my other templates to make them a little easier to read, but apparently when passing a URL to the wiki external link macro (function? helper?) it will not handle the leading space correctly.  So in short, using {{NSURL|url}} works but {{NSURL| url}} will not.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Mark - I spoke too soon.  It chokes on URL parameters.  So if I were to use {{Urltest|h t t p : / / w w w.something.com?test=1}} it will not parse the link correctly

Comment: @Steve K - yes, that is because of the ? (question mark). Replace it with %3F. If there is a | character in the URL, you have to replace it by %7C. See full list: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for the additional help, that did indeed solve the issue.

Comment: @SteveK The `{{urlencode:string}}` parser function has been much improved in recent years, so no extension (or ASCII table reference) is required to URLify template input parameters. I used this for an obfuscated `mailto:` template, where the email subject was passed as one of the parameters (the key part of the template was: `?subject={{urlencode:{{{subject|Hi there}}}|PATH}}`).

Comment: That said, the DuckDuckGo search engine will urlify arbitrary text for you with a query like 'url encode "Mutton, lettuce, and tomato sandwich"', which is easier than looking up one character at a time in some online reference (or `man ascii`). If you can be bothered, you also can type something like `encodeURIComponent("Wut? Huh? Allô?")` into the developer console of a web browser (usu. pressing F12 works to quickly open it) and you'll get back the URL-encoded version. _See also: [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)_